# Elasticsearch Won't Start when binding to anything but localhost (node validation exception when binding to eth0)

Tags: elasticsearch

I am VERY new to the elasticsearch game. I am even quite new to running JAVA things on my Ubuntu 14.04 install. My background is almost entirely JS stack based.

With that out of the way, I have ran through a tutorial for installing elasticsearch. I have managed to get it running on my cheapo digitalocean droplet by modifying how much memory it is assigned on start. Great!

I can access it fine if I am in the terminal on the actual host, using `http://localhost:9200/` for example.

However, I want to expose this as an endpoint. So according to documentation all over the net, I simply bing `netowrk.bind` to `0.0.0.0`.

However when I save the config file and `sudo service elasticsearch restart` it tells me it has started up. Shortly after it crashes and closes.

Upon closer inspection of the logs, it seems that because I am binding to a `non-loopback` network (aka eth0) it runs some bootstrap checks which then FAIL because I haven't got the minimum memory assigned to it.

Why will it let me bind it to *local* or localhost, and run the application but not allow me to bind to an outward facing network?

```
[2016-12-21T10:18:59,888][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapCheck     ] [honey-pot-1] 
bound or publishing to a non-loopback or non-link-local address,
enforcing bootstrap checks
[2016-12-21T10:18:59,903][ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap          ] [honey-pot-1]
node validation exception
bootstrap checks failed
max number of threads [1822] for user [elasticsearch] is too low, 
increase to at least [2048]
max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [100000] is too low,
increase to at least [262144]
[2016-12-21T10:18:59,928][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [honey-pot-1] 
stopping ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elastic won't start unless you increase the max number of threads and max virtual memory.
You can follow this doc:
[configuring Elastic system settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setting-system-settings.html)

Answer (score 2):

increase the max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count..use below command

$ sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144

Answer (score 1):

add the below config to /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml for rpm based installation or $ES_HOME/elasticsearch.yml for tarball installation

network.host: 127.0.0.1
http.host: 0.0.0.0

and restart elasticsearch. It should work.

Also, You can try setting setting - sudo systemctl edit elasticsearch and adding 
[Service]
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity

and saving and sudo systemctl daemon-reload
suggested above.